# How do you efficiently filter out older versions in a table representing multiple versions of the same logical object?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a table with rows that represents "Resources." When a resource changes, it gets another row in the same table, with the same "ID" field. ("ID" is unfortunately named, and doesn't actually represent a unique key.)

So the same logical Resource might have multiple columns, representing its change over time. Each row has a "Logged" column.  The row with the most recent "Logged" value, would be the current version of that Resource.

So, if resource A was created, and then has changed three times, it will have four rows in the table. If you order them by "Logged ASC," then you have the history of that resource, with the last row being its current state.

I want a view that represents the latest version of each resource.  This works:

```
SELECT * FROM Resources r1
WHERE ID =
  (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Resources r2 WHERE r1.ID = r2.ID ORDER BY Logged DESC)
```

So, the sub-SELECT gets the latest row for that ID ("TOP 1," when ordered by "Logged DESC"), then makes sure that's the only representation in that row in the outer SELECT.

This feels slow to me. And I can't help but think there's a better way (something involving a JOIN?), but it's just not coming to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Logged DESC) AS RN
FROM Resources
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE RN =1
```

Or another way might be

```
WITH T AS
(SELECT MAX(Logged) AS Logged,
        ID
FROM Resources
GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT R.*
FROM Resources R
JOIN T ON T.ID=R.ID AND T.Logged = R.Logged
```

Comment: 17 seconds vs. 0 seconds. Yes, I would say that does it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, not sure if it's faster:

`SELECT r1.* 
FROM Resources r1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT max(Logged) LoggedMAX, ID
    FROM Resources
    GROUP BY ID
) r2
  ON r1.ID = r2.ID
  AND r1.Logged = r2.LoggedMAX
ORDER BY r1.Logged desc`